# What can cause a "regular" type file not to be readable in Linux and how to identify this

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls

I'm iterating my entire filesystem looking for certain types of files using identifiers like magic numbers.

I've stumbled upon a few files that's supposed to be a "regular" (DT_REG) type file, but the file can't be read (the `read` system call returns error 38 - syscall not implemented). The files are called "alloc_calls" and are located in "/sys/kernel/slab/:d-xxxxxxx/" (where xxxxxxx is a number like 0001024).
Here's the output of `ls -l`, `file` and `cat` on one of those files:

```
root@VMint:/# ls -l /sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Aug  8 18:55 /sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls
root@VMint:/# file /sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls
/sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls: ERROR: cannot read /sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls' (Function not implemented)
root@VMint:/# cat /sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls
cat: '/sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls': Function not implemented
```

I've written some c code to demonstrate this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void main()
{
    char buf;
    int fd = open("/sys/kernel/slab/:d-0001024/alloc_calls", 0);
    perror("open");
    read(fd, &buf, 1);
    perror("read");
    printf("fd: %d, errno: %d\n",fd, errno);
}
```

Executing this code gives:

```
# gcc ./enosys.c -o enosys
# c_test sudo ./enosys           
open: Success
read: Function not implemented
fd: 3, errno: 38
```

How can a regular file be unreadable for root? Also, how can I identify such files?

Comment: The contents of /sys/kernel/slab are intended for use by the "slabinfo" tool. The kernel returns an error by default when reading these files, but they can be made readable by setting the "slub_debug" kernel command-line parameter (see [slub.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/slub.txt)). Or by echoing 1 to the "store_user" attribute file in each slab subdirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files in `/proc` and `/sys` are magic. They're not real files -- when you read and write them, you're actually reading and writing various kernel data structures.  (The `mount` command will show you that they're both mounted filesystems, of type `proc` and `sysfs` respectively.)

For any "file" that exists in either of those directories, it means there's a kernel data structure which someone thought it might be useful to expose in this way.  And to do the exposing, distinct code had to be set up to implement `read()` as fetching from the data structure, and `write()` as storing to it.

So, for a given kernel data structure that's exposed in this way, if what someone actually did was to implement (say) write but not read on the particular data structure, you'd see results like this.

What actually happens when you call `read()` is that the kernel looks up, for the filesystem and perhaps the individual file you're reading, which device-dependent implementation of `read` should be used for that file.  And if there isn't one, the error is (naturally enough) ENOSYS "syscall not implemented".

> Also, how can I identify such files?

I doubt there's a way!  But outside of `/proc` and `/sys`, it will probably never happen.  You'll probably want to exclude `/proc` and `/sys` from any automated searching like this, anyway -- there's lots of magic down there, so lots of weird things can happen when you start reading files indiscriminately.

Comment: I figured I'm protected against proc and other dark magic fake files by checking the file type. Oh well, I guess there's some issue with typing these files differently.

Comment: @Neowizard No, the "magic fake files" are all `S_IFREG` as far as `stat()` and therefore `find` and `ls -l` and every other program is concerned.  So, yes, you have to do something else to exclude them.  (So it's handy that, for example, both `tar` and `find` have ways to exclude whole subdirectory trees, `tar` with `-exclude` and `find` with `-path` and `-prune`.)